# How to add login functionality in Client-Server Android application?

Tags: php, android, session

I am working on a project, having a server in `php` and a client in `Android`. I want to add login functionality but unable to understand it that how the login works. A possible, may be wrong way is to authenticate the user when he logs in. If authenticate is successful open a session and send a unique token to the user and save the token in Android memory using `SharedPreferences` for the again communication. The purpose of using `sharedPreferences` is that if the user reopen the application, he will be directed to login state. The problem is in making `Session`. At first, make session once the user login and make new session each time when the application sends token means for each request. Kindly correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: PHP sessions? they're one way of establishing a login, but they're not the ONLY way.  plus,d efault php sessions tend to be short lived, especially under default settings where the session file is destroyed after a relatively short "idle" period. once that file's gone, the session is effectively dead.

Comment: @MarcB Can you refer me to other ways of adding `login` functionality when there is a server for data?

Comment: asking for documentation/tutorials is EXPLICITLY off-topic.

Comment: @MarcB Sir any thing? Any understanding? Any way of understanding it?

Comment: If you want to use 3rd party, you can opt firbase

Answer (score 0):

When app starts(splash acitivty) fetch the token from sharedpreff which will gives two scenarios given below

1 if the value u getting is null then redirect to LoginActivty where user enter the credentials to receive token and which will be stored in shared preff.

Make sure to clear the shredpreff value ie..token when user click logout button.

2 if you r getting token from sharedpreff means u r already login.

Comment: The problem is of `Session` . Where should I make session?

Comment: No use of `session`?